# Every time I run this function it is slower and slower

Tags: python, tkinter, time, while-loop, sleep

I am trying to do code a simple game in python using tkinter where a block jumps over obstacles, however I got stuck on the jumping part. Every time I call the jump function it jumps slower and slower, and I don't know the reason. Ty in advance.

```
import time
import tkinter
import random

bg = "white"
f = 2
k=0
t = 0.01
groundLevel = 550


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x600")

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root,width = 1000,height = 1000,bg = bg)
canvas.pack(fill= tkinter.BOTH, expand= True)

posX = 50

posY= 530

startButton = tkinter.Button(canvas,text="                               Start                               ")

def startPlayer(xx,yy):
    canvas.create_rectangle(xx-20,yy-22,xx+20,yy+18,fill = "orange")
    return(xx,yy)

def move(x,y,x2,y2,direction,fill,outline):
    global f
    #direction 0 = up
    #direction 1 = down
    #direction 2 = left
    #direction 3 = right
    if direction == 0:
        canvas.create_rectangle(x,y,x2,y2,fill="cyan",outline="cyan")
        canvas.create_rectangle(x,y-f,x2,y2-f,fill=fill,outline=outline)
    if direction == 1:
        canvas.create_rectangle(x,y,x2,y2,fill="cyan",outline="cyan")
        canvas.create_rectangle(x,y+f,x2,y2+f,fill=fill,outline=outline)
    if direction == 2:
        canvas.create_rectangle(x,y,x2,y2,fill="cyan",outline="cyan")
        canvas.create_rectangle(x,y,x2,y2,fill=fill,outline=outline)
    if direction == 3:
        canvas.create_rectangle(x,y,x2,y2,fill="cyan",outline="cyan")
        canvas.create_rectangle(x,y,x2,y2,fill=fill,outline=outline)


def playerJump():
    global groundLevel, f, k,posX,posY,t
    while k != 1:
        move(posX-20,posY-22,posX+20,posY+18,direction = 0, fill = "orange",outline = "black")
        posY -= 2
        canvas.update()
        if (posY) == 480:
            k = 1
        time.sleep(t)
    k = 0
    while k != 1:
        move(posX-20,posY-22,posX+20,posY+18,direction = 1, fill = "orange",outline = "black")
        posY += 2
        canvas.update()
        if (posY) == 530:
            k = 1
        time.sleep(t)
    k = 0
    
    

def start():
    canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,1000,600,fill="cyan")
    canvas.create_line(0,550,1000,550,width = 3)
    startButton.destroy()
    startPlayer(50,530)
    startGameButton = tkinter.Button(canvas, text ="Go!",command = playerJump)
    startGameButton.place(x = 35, y=400)
    return(startGameButton)
    
def resetButton():
    global startGameButton
    startGameButton.destroy()
    startGameButton = tkinter.Button(canvas, text ="Go!",command = playerJump)
    startGameButton.place(x = 35, y=400)


startImage = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/marti/OneDrive/Desktop/Wheel finder/startSign.png")

canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,1000,1000,fill="green")

startButton.config(image = startImage,command = start)
startButton.place(x = 130, y= 25)

canvas.create_rectangle(300,400,700,500,fill="#113B08",outline = "black",width = 3)
canvas.create_text(500,450,text = "By: --------", font = "Arial 30",fill ="white")
```

I shrinking the sleep time every time it runs so its faster, but that is only a temporary solution and it didn't even work.

Comment: don't use `while` loops and don't use `time.sleep`, you probably want to watch a `pygame` tutorial and see how the logic is done there and then imagine that you have one `after` "loop" that's basically your main game loop and you do everything there on a per-frame basis, also you probably just want to use `pygame` for gamedev anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with your code is you are always adding new items into your canvas. When you jump you update orange rectangle and repaint its old place. However they stack top of each other and handling too many elements makes slower your program.

We create player and return it to main function.

```
def startPlayer(xx,yy):
    player=canvas.create_rectangle(xx-20,yy-22,xx+20,yy+18,fill = "orange")
    return player
```

This is new start function. Check that we get player and send to playerjump function.

```
def start():
    canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,1000,600,fill="cyan")
    canvas.create_line(0,550,1000,550,width = 3)
    startButton.destroy()
    player = startPlayer(50,530)
    startGameButton = tkinter.Button(canvas, text ="Go!",command = lambda :playerJump(player))
    startGameButton.place(x = 35, y=400)
    return(startGameButton)
```

And this is playerjump function.We get player and sent to move function.

```
def playerJump(player):
    global groundLevel, f, k,posX,posY,t
    while k != 1:
        move(posX-20,posY-22,posX+20,posY+18,direction = 0, fill = "orange",outline = "black",player=player)
        posY -= 2
        canvas.update()
        if (posY) == 480:
            k = 1
        time.sleep(t)
    k = 0
    while k != 1:
        move(posX-20,posY-22,posX+20,posY+18,direction = 1, fill = "orange",outline = "black",player=player)
        posY += 2
        canvas.update()
        if (posY) == 530:
            k = 1
        time.sleep(t)
    k = 0
```

Except move lines, I didn't change anything in this function.

Okay now let's check key part.

```
def move(x,y,x2,y2,direction,fill,outline,player):
    global f
    #direction 0 = up
    #direction 1 = down
    #direction 2 = left
    #direction 3 = right
    if direction == 0:
        canvas.coords(player,x,y-f,x2,y2-f)
    if direction == 1:
        canvas.coords(player,x,y+f,x2,y2+f)
    if direction == 2:
        canvas.coords(player,x,y,x2,y2)
    if direction == 3:
        canvas.coords(player,x,y,x2,y2)
```

look that instead of creating new rectangles,we updated existing one. which is much more stable

Also you forgot adding root.mainloop in your code snippet.